# Perl6: use module inside other module

Tags: module, filepath, raku

I have 4 files.

- C:\perlCode2\start.pl6
- C:\perlCode2\file0.pm6
- C:\perlCode2\folder1\file1.pm6
- C:\perlCode2\folder2\file2.pm6

start.pl6 is used to run my program. The 3 module files contain or generate data that is eventually used by start.pl6. I use atom.io to run the code.

Here is the code:

start.pl6:

```
use v6;
use lib ".";
use file0;
use lib "folder1";
use file1;
use lib "folder2";
use file2;

say 'start';
my $file0 = file0.new();
say $file0.mystr;
my $file1 = file1.new();
say $file1.mystr;
my $file2 = file2.new();
say $file2.mystr;
say 'end';
```

file0.pm6:

```
class file0 is export {
  has Str $.mystr = "file 0";

  submethod BUILD() {
    say "hello file 0";
  }
}
```

file1.pm6:

```
class file1 is export {
  has Str $.mystr = "file 1";
}
```

file2.pm6:

```
class file2 is export {
  has Str $.mystr = "file 2";
}
```

output:

```
start
hello file 0
file 0
file 1
file 2
end
[Finished in 0.51s]
```

Rather than making instances of all 3 module files inside start.pl6, I want to create an instance of file2 inside file1, and of file1 inside file0. This way I only have to create an instance of file0 in start.pl6 to see the same output;

**Here are the changes I had in mind:**

file1.pm6:

```
use lib "../folder2";
use "file2.pl6"; 

class file1 is export {
  has Str $.mystr = "file 1";

  submethod BUILD() {
    my $file2 = file2.new();
    $!mystr = $!mystr ~ "\n" ~ $file2.mystr; 
        # I want to instantiate file2 inside the constructor, 
        # so I can be sure the line
        # $!mystr = $!mystr ~ "\n" ~ $file2.mystr; 
        # takes effect before i call any of file0's methods;
  }
}
```

file0.pm6:

```
use lib "folder1";
use "file1.pl6"; 

class file0 is export {
  has Str $.mystr = "file 0";

  submethod BUILD() {
    say "hello file 0";
    my $file1 = file1.new();
    $!mystr = $!mystr ~ "\n" ~ $file1.mystr; 
  }
}
```

In file0, the lines 
use lib "folder1";
use "file1.pl6";
 yields this error:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling C:\perlCode2\file0.pm6 (file0)
'use lib' may not be pre-compiled
at C:\perlCode2\file0.pm6 (file0):2
------> use lib "folder1/file1.pl6"<HERE>;
[Finished in 0.584s]
```

I file1, the line 
use lib "../folder2";
use "file2";
doesnt work but also doesnt give an error. I just get the output:
[Finished in 0.31s]

In the end, the file start.pl6 should look like this to produce the output:

start.pl6:

```
use v6;
use lib ".";
use file0;

say 'start';
my $file0 = file0.new();
say $file0.mystr;
say 'end';
```

output:

```
start
hello file 0
file 0
file 1
file 2
end
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `use lib "folder2/file2.pl6"` with `use lib "../folder2/file2.pm6"` (in `file1.pm6`)?

Comment: yes, weirdly I dont get an error. I jus get "[Finished in 0.331s]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do makes no sense to me. It seems you are putting those modules in folders arbitrarily.

---

If the names of those modules does make sense here is how I might structure it.

```
C:\perlCode2\start.pl6
C:\perlCode2\lib\file0.pm6
C:\perlCode2\lib\folder1\file1.pm6
C:\perlCode2\lib\folder2\file2.pm6
```

*start.pl6*:

```perl6
use v6;

END say "[Finished in {(now - $*INIT-INSTANT).fmt("%0.2fs")}";

use lib 'lib';
use file0;

say 'start';
my $file0 = file0.new;
say $file0.mystr;
say 'end';
```

*lib\file0.pm6*:

```perl6
use folder1::file1;

class file0 is export {
  has Str $.mystr = "file 0";

  submethod TWEAK() {
    say "hello file 0";
    $!mystr ~= "\n" ~ folder1::file1.new.mystr; 
  }
}
```

*lib\folder1\file1.pm6*:

```perl6
use folder2::file2;

class folder1::file1 is export {
  has Str $.mystr = "file 1";

  submethod TWEAK() {
    $!mystr ~= "\n" ~ folder2::file2.new.mystr;
  }
}
```

*lib\folder2\file2.pm6*

```perl6
class folder2::file2 is export {
  has Str $.mystr = "file 2";
}
```

---

Answer (score 2):

```
use lib "folder2/file2.pl6";
```

This does not do what you think it does. use lib expects a **directory** where Perl should be looking for modules, not the path to some script.

If your My.pm6 is in ./lib (in respect to the current working directory) then

```
use lib "lib";
use My;
```

does the trick. You can also use absolute paths

```
use lib "~/projects/perl6/MyProject/lib";
use My;
```

See [lib](https://docs.perl6.org/language/modules#index-entry-use_lib).

Comment: In my testing, I don't see how that works. According to the error message, `use lib ...` just plain can't be used in a module. The test is as simple as: `mkdir lib; echo "use lib 'lib';" > test.pm6; perl6 -I. -Mtest -e "say 'success'"`

Comment: You don't put "use lib" into the module, you put it into the script that "use"s the module.

Comment: Gotcha. I misunderstood where you were saying to put the code. The module name should have clued me in.

Comment: @Holli does that mean that you cant use a module inside another module?

Comment: No, of course not. It just means modules don't care about path names. All you need to do is to tell Perl where to *start* *looking* *for* modules.

You can do this by either using "use lib" in the consuming code (aka script) or by setting the PERL6LIB environment variable to point at a directory where - again - Perl will start searching for modules.